# httpErrors config section not working in Windows Azure

Tags: asp.net, azure, http-status-code-404, http-error

My website is configured to display a custom HTML-page when an error occurs. This works fine on both IIS and ASP.NET Development Server. However, as soon as I deploy the application to Windows Azure, I get HTTP 500 instead of 404 for non-ASP.NET-URLs.

This is what the relevant web.config-sections look like:

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
  <clear />
  <error statusCode="404" path="/Public/Error404.html" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
</httpErrors>

<customErrors defaultRedirect="/Public/Error.html" mode="On">
    <error redirect="/Public/Error404.html" statusCode="404" />
</customErrors>
```

The `customErrors` section (applied to URLs ending on .aspx) works properly. The `httpErrors` section doesn't, however. Even though Azure's IIS sends a 500 to the browser, it logs a 404:

> 2012-02-10 13:30:07 W3SVC1273337584 RD00155D3A1439 10.61.70.39 GET
>   /asdfdsaafds - 80 - 65.52.128.172 HTTP/1.1
>   Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+8.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/4.0;+SLCC2;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729;+.NET+CLR+3.0.30729;+.NET4.0C;+.NET4.0E) - - 940af2dbd9df4924b87a13878752aee3.cloudapp.net 404 0 2 222 457 218

Locally, I get a HTTP 500.19 with some more detailed information:

> The requested page cannot be accessed because the related
>   configuration data for the page is invalid.
>
> Config Error  Lock violation
>
> 238: `<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" defaultPath="/Public/Error.html" existingResponse="Replace" defaultResponseMode="ExecuteURL">`

Googling lock violation didn't help me too much, as results usually told me about Standalone IIS. There aren't any errors in the Windows event log.

I'd like to display the `Error404.html` for any 404 on both Azure and Standalone IIS. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the obvious question is: have you made sure your custom error page is actually deployed to your Azure Web Role instance?

Second question: does it work in the Azure emulator?

Update:
The error message indicates that the config section is locked on your target IIs.
Read this [Introduction to ApplicationHost.config](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/124/introduction-to-applicationhostconfig/).
You probably need to unlock the httpErrors section.

Also, take a look at [this solution](http://forums.iis.net/t/1159721.aspx) for a similar error.

Comment: I edited my question. It is deployed (displayed for aspx-404s), but it does not work locally. Thank you anyway, checking this gave me a little more insight.

Comment: Thank you so much! I stupidly ignored those hints as I didn't expect to touch the underlying IIS itself. Now all I have to find is a way to persist these changes over further updates and re-deployments...

Comment: How do you unlock the section on an Azure web site?  Doesn't seem to be anything to edit applicationhost.config.